# trying to use a search form to show results from the database of products

Tags: php, mysql, forms, model-view-controller

i have 3 tables within my db: users, lots and auction

lots contains lotid, title, desc, photo, and fk a_id and this table is products and links to auction through a_id as that shows whos selling product

auction contains a_id,name, address and date. this table is basically the seller info

users contains all information related to logging in and out

currently on my website you can register login and logout without anyissues now im trying to add a search onto the page so you can search for items that are listed and it should return the output showing all fields from lotid and also show the auction data so the data returned is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucn8y.png)

the db has a few records for now but will be populated with around 500 lot records and 50 auction records so the search needs to be able to go through this and only return relevant information the search criteria should be for example: theres 100 types of phone if i search "phone" it should show iphones aswell as anything else that contains phone within the title so red phone would return aswell. but currently im really struggling and have massive errors im new to using mvc so it could be im using the wrong files like views models etc but my log in system works fine so i need help adding this search function as currently its like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4xdH.png) when i tested it here is my [directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzdiD.png) i currently tried this search function by adding the search form to the auction.php page and using the users.php controller although i may need new controller for this page

code for auction.php

```
<?php
require APPROOT . '/views/includes/head.php';
?>
<div class="navbar">
    <?php
    require APPROOT . '/views/includes/navigation.php';
    ?>
    
</div>
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit" name="submit-search"></button>
</form>

<h1> this is Auction Page </h1>
<h2>All products</h2>

<div class="product-container">
    <?php
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM article");
    ?>

</div>
```

user model code

```
<?php
class User{
    private $db;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = new Database;
    }

    public function getUsers(){
        $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

        $result = $this->db->resultSet();

        return $result;
    }

    public function register($data){
        $this->db->query('INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) 
        VALUES (:username, :email, :password)');

        //bind values
        $this->db->bind(':username', $data['username']);
        $this->db->bind(':email', $data['email']);
        $this->db->bind(':password', $data['password']);

        //execute
        if ($this->db->execute()){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function login($username, $password){
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username');

        //bind value
        $this->db->bind(':username', $username);

        $row = $this->db->single();

        $hashedPassword = $row->password;
        if (password_verify($password, $hashedPassword)){
            return $row;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    //Find user by email email is passed as argument from controller
    public function findUserByEmail($email){
        $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');

        //email param binded with variabel
        $this->db->bind(':email', $email);

        //check if email is already registered
        if ($this->db->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

my users controller

```
<?php
class Users extends Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        $this->userModel = $this->model('User');
    }

    public function register(){
        $data = [
            'username' => '',
            'email' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'confirmPassword' => '',
            'usernameError' => '',
            'emailError' => '',
            'passwordError' => '',
            'confirmPasswordError' => ''
        ];

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            //Sanitize post data
            $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            $data = [
                'username' => trim($_POST['username']),
                'email' => trim($_POST['email']),
                'password' => trim($_POST['password']),
                'confirmPassword' => trim($_POST['confirmPassword']),
                'usernameError' => '',
                'emailError' => '',
                'passwordError' => '',
                'confirmPasswordError' => ''
            ];

            $nameValidation = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/";
            $passwordValidation = "/^(.{0,7}|[^a-z]*|[^\d]*)£/i";
            //validate username only allow letters and numbers
            if (empty($data['username'])) {
                $data['usernameError'] = 'Please enter a username.';
            } elseif (!preg_match($nameValidation, $data['username'])) {
                $data['usernameError'] = 'Name can only contain letters and numbers.';
            }
            if (empty($data['email'])) {
                $data['emailError'] = 'Please enter an email address.';
            }elseif (!filter_var($data['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                $data['emailError'] = 'Please enter a VALID email address.';
            }else{
                //Check if email exists.
                if ($this->userModel->findUserByEmail($data['email'])){
                    $data['emailError'] = 'Email address is registered to an existing account';
                }
            }

            //Validate password min password and numbers
            if (empty($data['password'])){
                $data['passwordError'] = 'Please enter a password';
            }elseif(strlen($data['password']) < 6){
                $data['passwordError'] = 'Password must be greater than 6 characters';
            } elseif (preg_match($passwordValidation, $data['password'])) {
                $data['passwordError'] = 'Password MUST contain atleast one number.';
            }
            //validate confirm password matches password
            if (empty($data['confirmPassword'])) {
                $data['confirmPasswordError'] = 'Please confirm password';
            }else{
                if ($data['password'] != $data['confirmPassword']){
                    $data['confirmPasswordError'] = 'Passwords do not match';
                }
            }

            //make sure that errors are empty
            if (empty($data['usernameError']) && empty($data['emailError']) &&
                empty($data['passwordError']) && empty($data['confirmPasswordError'])){

                //hash password
                $data['password'] = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                //register user from model
                if ($this->userModel->register($data)){
                    //redirect to login page after registering
                    header('location: ' . URLROOT . '/users/login');
                }else{
                    die('Something went wrong');
                }
            }
        }

        $this->view('users/register', $data);
    }

    public function login(){
        $data = [
            'title' => 'Login Page',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'usernameError' =>'',
            'passwordError' =>''
        ];

        //check for post
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            //sanitize post data preventing people from trying to manipulate using js
            $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING  );

            $data = [
                'username' => trim($_POST['username']),
                'password' => trim($_POST['password']),
                'usernameError' => '',
                'passwordError' => '',
            ];
            //validate username
            if (empty($data['username'])){
                $data['usernameError'] = 'Please enter a username';
            }
            //validate password
            if (empty($data['password'])){
                $data['passwordError'] = 'Please enter a password';
            }

            //check if all errors empty
            if (empty($data['usernameError']) && empty($data['passwordError'])){
                $loggedInUser = $this->userModel->login($data['username'], $data['password']);

                if ($loggedInUser){
                    $this->createUserSession($loggedInUser);
                }
            }else{
                $data['passwordError'] = 'Password or Username is incorrect. Please try again';

                $this->view('users/login', $data);
            }

        }else{
            $data = [
                'username' => '',
                'password' => '',
                'usernameError' =>'',
                'passwordError' =>''
            ];
        }

        $this->view('users/login', $data);
    }

    public function createUserSession($user){
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user->username;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $user->email;
        header('location:' . URLROOT . '/pages/index');
    }

    public function logout(){
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        unset($_SESSION['email']);
        header('location:' . URLROOT . '/users/login');
    }

    public function Search(){

    }
}
```

Comment: when i click the search button it opens up a new search page as it should be the results should be displayed on this page so the way it works is i go on auction page type in something then click search then it loads this search page with the results of the search

Comment: You really need to narrow down your question to a specific problem. You have a lengthy description and lots of code, while you only mention one error on a specific line. Considering that `auction.php` is not a class, what do you expect `$this->db` to be?

Comment: basically i dont know where im suppose to code this i haver so maby different classes and stuff for the mvc im trying to do the search of my database but i keep getting errors ive been moving code all over to try and fix it

Comment: my database connection is in the config file my database.php file has bind query methods and then i have tried to do my search query on auction.php

Comment: Still, `$this` is a special keyword that's only valid in a class/object context. Seems like you need to go through some OOP basics tutorial to help you understand how things work. You're running ahead of yourself - you don't seem to understand it, but you're trying to use it. Learn before you use, or you'll just end up blindly chasing errors like this.

Comment: could you guide me as to what file i should be doing this code in to make the search work should i put it in the users controller?

Comment: Once again - you're running ahead of yourself. You don't seem to fully understand some basics and you're trying to comprehend MVC. Learn more about classes, variable scope and debugging before you try to employ a design pattern, otherwise it's like you're trying to build an entire city without knowing how to build a single house. Do you understand why you're getting the error? If the answer is no, then MVC structure shouldn't be your priority. You can settle that once you make the code work.

Comment: its for an exam thats why im rushing ahead i dont have hours to learn fully i only hAVE BASIC UNDERSTANDING (didnt mean caps)